# Download entire dataset from a .pbix file

Tags: powerbi

I have no luck finding answers online, so I resorted to posting the question here. I just want to know if there is a way to export an entire dataset to Excel from a .pbix report in Power BI Desktop? The .pbix report is a dashboard that contains multiple tabs.

I am doing the same report but through Excel. Another group is tasked to use Power BI to come up with the same report, but the results differ. I wanted to be able to extract the dataset from Power BI for me to run a comparison and know where the discrepancy lies. This other group cannot provide me the raw data for professional reasons.

Comment: Any reason both reports can't have identical Power Query queries? Can you copy the queries from the .pbix?

Answer (score 0):

For a report published to Power BI online, you can choose the [Analyze in Excel](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-analyze-in-excel/) option.

I'm not sure if that can be done directly from the desktop app without publishing or not.